# Prove the product of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Prove that

$$\left(1+x^{-1}\right)\cdot\left(1+x^{-2}\right)\cdot\left(1+x^{-4}\right)\dots\dots\left(1+x^{-2^n}\right)=\frac{x}{x-1}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{2^{(n+1)}}}\right)$$

I thought a lot about this, but didn't get any breakthroughs. Please help me here.

Comment: Did you try induction ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Multiply and divide the LHS by $(x-1)$. And use the identity $(a-b)(a+b)=(a^{2}-b^{2})$.

Comment: thank u so much, so stupid of me

Comment: @user3290550, Accept my answet as a gesture of gratitude ;-)

Answer (score 1):

$$F_n=(1+x^{-1})(1+x^{-2})(1+x^{-4}).......(1-x^{2^n})$$
Multiply by $(1-x^{-1})$ on both sides, then
$$F_n \frac{1-x}{x}=(1-x^{-1}) (1+x^{-2}) (1+x^{4}).....(1-x^{-2^n})$$
Using $(a-b)(a+b)=(a^2-b^2)$ repetedly we get
$$F_n=\frac{x}{1-x}  (1-x^{-2^{n+1}})$$